Connection not slowing with Fiddler's 'Simulate Modem Speeds'
I've installed Fiddler in order to test my application with a slow internet connection.
I've enabled the "Rules/Performance/Simulate Modem Speeds" and in "Customise Rules..." ensured the following code is there (which it was by default)
    if (m_SimulateModem) {
        // Delay sends by 300ms per KB uploaded.
        oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "300"; 
        // Delay receives by 150ms per KB downloaded.
        oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "150"; 
    }

However, when I run my application, the connection speed is as fast as ever, e.g. downloading a 400MB file in just about 20 seconds, and I just participated in an MS teams video call without any problems.
My application is a C# one that uses HttpClient to retrieve the aforementioned file.
Is there something I need to do to maybe feed my application through Fiddler so that it is affected by its "Simulate Modem" feature?

Do you see your applications' requests in Fiddler? Even if you enable "Act a system proxy at start-up" some programs ignore Windows proxy settings. I would also check if Streaming mode in Fiddler is disabled.

@Robert - Yes I saw the request in Fiddler and Streaming mode is disabled.

Are you per chance testing with localhost? In this case it could help using your machine name ("mymachinename") instead of "localhost"

@swobi - No it's a remote host. I have, however, managed to achieved the desired effect with "Clumsy"

You could try to add a debug message to the slowdown code:
if (m_SimulateModem) {
    // Delay sends by 300ms per KB uploaded.
    oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "300"; 
    // Delay receives by 150ms per KB downloaded.
    oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "150"; 
    FiddlerObject.log("Slowdown active!");
} 

or you can use ”extreme” values (eg. 5000ms) to check if the code is executed in your scenario.

@Robert: You are absolutely right with both your points! I changed “MessageBox.Show” to “FiddlerObject.log” and corrected the quotes. Thanks for pointing it out.
